# Bootstrap justify-right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Good day,

I have a question.
I am working on a website where I want the menu to be right aligned.

[image]

In theory it should be :

```
    <ul class="nav justify-content-end">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

However it isn't aligning right.
So I am doing something wrong.

And I am missing my error.
I hope that someone could point me my blame.
Because I am missing it. Fiddling with it for a couple of hours by now and it is driving me nuts.

My code is :

```
                    <ul class="nav justify-content-end" id="vpMenu">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Explore <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="index.html">Home</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="explore.html">Explore</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="listing.html">Listing</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="single-listing.html">Single Listing</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Listings <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="index.html">Home</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="explore.html">Explore</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="listing.html">Listing</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="single-listing.html">Single Listing</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

I have put the source code online since my blame is probably somewhere in my CSS code:

- Edit:

By : **Manny**

```
<ul class="nav justify-content-end" id="vpMenu">
```

to

```
<ul class="nav ml-auto justify-content-end" id="vpMenu">
```

**.ml-auto**
Was the solution!

> Auto margins
>
> Flexbox can do some pretty awesome things when you mix flex alignments
>   with auto margins. Shown below are three examples of controlling flex
>   items via auto margins: default (no auto margin), pushing two items to
>   the right (.mr-auto), and pushing two items to the left (.ml-auto).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try, change `<ul class="nav justify-content-end" id="vpMenu">`
to `<ul class="nav ml-auto justify-content-end" id="vpMenu">`

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6lbkgc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html&view=preview)